# How to hide credits text in fusion charts using css

Tags: css, fusioncharts

I need to hide "Fusion charts XT trial" text while displaying the chart.
I tried to hide this using css but it's not getting solved.

```
#css
    .raphael-group-423-creditgroup {
          display:none;
```

Comment: You should buy this product.

Comment: is there any way to do this other than buying ?? @JeroenHeier

Answer (score 13):

In your CSS file just write

```
svg > g[class^="raphael-group-"] > text{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: And is that even legal? I read their license, but could not find anything related

Answer (score 3):

```
<style type="text/css">
    g[class$='creditgroup'] {
         display:none !important;
    }
</style>
```

This worked for me and I guess it's simple and will work for all.

You can make it even more specific.

```
<style type="text/css">
    g[class^='raphael-group-'][class$='-creditgroup'] {
         display:none !important;
    }
</style>
```

**Enjoy illegality ;)**

Answer (score 2):

1. Simple Edit your *fusioncharts.js*
2. Find *fontSize:9,fontFamily:"Verdana,sans"*
3. Set font size 9 to 0

Answer (score 2):

```
[pointer-events="bounding-box"] {
    display: none
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, I am happy about the help center link. I found this solution when I tried to hide the watermark from the different charts of my page and noticed this attribute is common in all of them. So, I thought to share the code with you all. 

Again, I will try to improve my writing skills.

Answer (score 1):

It working for me, paste it to your css file

```
svg > g[class^='raphael-group-'] g {
     fill: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var item = document.body.querySelector('.raphael-group-423-creditgroup');
item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It working for me

> div[id^='fc-'] > span > svg > defs + g > g:nth-child(26) {
> display:none !important;
> }

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet. While this code may answer the question, providing [additional context regarding how and/or why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

using d3 lib

```js
d3.selectAll("svg g[class$='-creditgroup'] text").attr("style","display: none");
```